# cppcms, retrieving values from form

Tags: c++, cppcms

I would like to know how to retrieve POST fields from a pure
html file, without using a class which inherit from cppcms::form.
I want the class which implements 
For example with this class:

```
std::string Index::main(const std::string &url, const std::map<std::string, std::string> parameters)
{
 std::string out = (
        "<html>\n"
        "<body>\n"
        "<form name='test' action='' method='post'>"
        "<h1>Hello, put your name here:</h1><br />"
        "<input type='text' name='user'>"
        "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
        "</form>"
        "</body>\n"
        "</html>\n"
 );

  return out;
}
```

This method is called in a class which inherit from cppcms::application:

```
void Engine::main(const std::string &url)
{
   std::map<std::string, std::string> params;

   pages["/"] = boost::bind(&Index::main, boost::shared_ptr<Index>(new Index), _1, _2);
   std::string out = pages[url](url, params); // Call to Index::main

   response().out() << out;
 }
```

What I would like to do is retrieving the "user" field and putting it into the "params" map without having to make my Index class inherit from cppcms::form or using the "get" method inside of "post". 
I want the html files/classes to be completely independents from the cppcms framework.
Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: I found how to do it with: std::string value = request().post("user");

Answer (score 0):

You still want to use cppcms::forms even if you don't use automatic form (HTML) generation.

Why? Many good reasons: CSRF validation, encoding validation, various settings validation, etc, etc, etc.

You can setup the parameters you need like username.name("user") in `cppcms::form::widgets` classes but still use forms framework.

```
cppcms::widgets::text username;
username.name("user");
// validation - what you need
username.non_empty()

// single widget loading
username.load(context());
if(username.validate()) {
   myname=username.value();
}

// better as you can handle several widgets at once
cppcms::form frm;
frm.add(username);
...
frm.load(context())
if(frm.validate()) {
  ...
  myname=username.value();
}
```

Comment: That's indeed better for me to use cppcms::form but if one day I want to switch to another framework (made by my own) it would be difficult.And I also want to be able to create my website with a WYSIWYG tool, if I use cppcms widgets that won't be possible anymore =/

Comment: (a) Never... ever use WYSIWYG tools for any sort of real web development... (b) You can still create your own HTML, however it is strongly recommended to validate the POST data via forms framework. Otherwise you would open huge security holes in your apps easily.

Comment: Thanks for these advices. And yes, after trying many WYSIWYG editors I decided to move to eclipse IDE...